# Newline in Gnuplot-Py?

Tags: python, gnuplot, data-visualization

I'm using the [GnuplotPy](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) interface to use Gnuplot from inside of Python. I've found that GnuplotPy complains when I have a newline in a GnuplotPy call. For example:

```
import Gnuplot
gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist = 1)
gp('set title "My plot title is very long, \n so it needs two lines"')
...
gp.plot(...)
```

The above code throws the following error while running:

```
gnuplot> so it needs two lines
     ^
     line 0: invalid command
```

And, the above code outputs a plot that only shows the first line of the title, but the plot is otherwise correct. If I remove the `\n` in the `gp('set title...')` line, then the error goes away.

---

According to [this Gnuplot tutorial](http://www.sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gnuplot-3.7.1/html_node/gnuplot_245.html), `\n` is indeed a valid way of doing a multi-line label in Gnuplot. For example, the tutorial suggests doing this:

```
set title "This is the title\n\nThis is the x2label"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gnuplot and python both take the 2-character sequence (`\n`) as a newline.  What's happening is that python is intercepting your `\n` and translating it to a literal newline which gnuplot chokes on.  Try using a raw string:

```
gp(r'set title "My plot title is very long, \n so it needs two lines"')
#  ^ The leading r makes it a raw string.
```

This will prevent python from intercepting your newline.

Comment: That works! Some of my newlines are falling off the page, though. Any advice for how to pad the edges of the plot so that several lines of text will fit in a label?

Comment: @solvingPuzzles -- I don't think I understand what you mean by the newlines falling off the page...

Comment: Let's say I'm setting some custom multiline `xtics`. `gp(r'set xtics add (1 "this \n is \n a \n multiline \n label"')` In my particular example, `this \n is \n a` fits on the page, but the words `multiline` and `label` are missing, as their locations are beyond the bottom of the page.

Comment: @solvingPuzzles -- I see.  You could try `set bmargin at screen .1` gradually increasing the number until your whole label fits.